Websocket Connection Failed Django javascript
I am trying to connect to my websocket from the frontend in javascript
const url = 'wss://chatapprender.onrender.com/${person_id}/';

I am using django channels for backend
ASGI_urlpatterns = [       path("websocket/\<int:id\>/", consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi())      ]

When the following line is executed it gives this error in the console
WebSocket connection to 'wss://chatapprender.onrender.com/3/' failed:
connectToWebsocket @ script.js:71
(anonymous) @ script.js:190

it works on my local 127.0.01:8000 server of django
with this url ws://127.0.0.1:8000/websocket/${person_id}
but when i deploy it it fails to connect
    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'channels',
        'daphne',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'chat',
        'accounts',
    ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mychatproject.wsgi.application'
    ASGI_APPLICATION = 'mychatproject.asgi.application'

routing.py
    from django.urls import path
    from . import consumers
    ASGI_urlpatterns = [
        path("websocket/<int:id>/", consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi())
    ]

asgi.py
    import os
    from chat import routing
    from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
    from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
    from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mychatproject.settings')

    application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
        'http':get_asgi_application(),
        'websocket':AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(routing.ASGI_urlpatterns))
    })

consumers.py
    class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
        def connect(self):
            self.accept()
            try:
                user_channel = UserChannel.objects.get(user=self.scope.get('user'))
                user_channel.channel_name=self.channel_name
                user_channel.save()
            except:
                user_channel=UserChannel.objects.create(user=self.scope.get('user'),
                                                    channel_name=self.channel_name)
                user_channel.save()
                self.person_id=self.scope.get("url_route").get("kwargs").get("id")

